# sudo update-grub: *******#: not found

Tags: grub2

I wanted to edit my GRUB config file and used `sudo update-grub` to update it, but I got the output:

```
Sourcing file `enter code here`/etc/default/grub
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 1: /etc/default/grub: *******#: not found
```

Those *s are some numbers similar to my account password. I also tried `sudo update-grub2` but it also didn't work. What can I do?

Comment: You must have messed up your `\etc\default\grub` file. Did you do a backup of it before editing it?

Comment: What is the output of `cat /etc/default/grub`?

Comment: I guess you prepended those asterisks to some comment which has to _start_ with `#`.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with the command `update-grub` (which is actually a little shortcut for the command `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`) on your system. You have simply inserted some junk text into your `/etc/default/grub` file somehow when you were editing it:

```
zanna@toaster:~$ sudo update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 35: /etc/default/grub: junk: not found
```

In my case the `junk` is on line 35. In your case, it's in line 1. Either you inserted the bad text at the beginning, or you overwrote the whole file.

You can probably fix this by editing the file again and removing the line containing `*******` (or whatever that represents in your question), and any other lines you inserted which should not be there.

You will usually find the most recently downloaded package maintainer's version of the file for your system at `/var/lib/ucf/cache/:etc:default:grub`. You may read this file by running, for example:

```
cat /var/lib/ucf/cache/:etc:default:grub
```

You may see the differences between your edited file and this one by running, for example:

```
diff /var/lib/ucf/cache/:etc:default:grub /etc/default/grub
```

And in the worst case scenario that you need to replace your missing or broken `/etc/default/grub` then you could use this command (note that **the existing `/etc/default/grub` is silently overwritten by this command**).

```
sudo cp /var/lib/ucf/cache/:etc:default:grub /etc/default/grub
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the file `/etc/default/grub` exists. If not, create one, for example as below:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

You can try:

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Also refer to [this Ubuntu Forums thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2077859).

Comment: Hey ARJUN, welcome to [ubuntu.se]. I generally suggest people not to copy grub configuration blindly from other system. The current system may/may not have some customizations which may be lost if grub is copied over there.

Comment: I do not think the problem is that the file does not exist, rather that it contains some junk.